# Compute $\oint_{S^1}\frac{z}{\sin^{3}(z/2)}dz$ without using Laurent series

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, residue-calculus

Let $D=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z|<1 \}$. How to compute the integral :
$$\int_{+\partial D}\frac{z}{\sin^{3}(z/2)}dz$$ 
without using Laurent series?

My trouble is that I cannot find the poles and the residues.

Comment: Hint: The function $$z\mapsto z/\sin^3(z/2)$$ is **even**.

Comment: @Did so beacuse the integral is on a closed curve the integral is 0 ?

Comment: Closed curve is not enough, but you integrate on the unit circle, and...

Comment: @Did sorry i did not understan why it came 0 , ok it's even , sorry but i really can0t understand

Comment: The integral on the circle can be rewritten as an integral on $(0,2\pi)$ and you know that, if $z=e^{it}$ with $t$ in $(0,2\pi)$ then $z/\sin^3(z/2)=f(t)$ where $f(t+\pi)=f(t)$ for every $t$ in $(0,\pi)$. Thus the integral on $(0,2\pi)$ is...

Comment: ok i know that this may sounds stupid , but, you sayin that i can substitute z with $e^{it}$ ? so the denominator is a sum of exponentials ?

Comment: Yes the integral is on the unit circle hence the change of variable $z=e^{it}$ is canonical. After that, the idea is to avoid messing up with the details of the function but to only use that it is $f(t)$ for some function $f$ such that $f(t+\pi)=f(t)$.

Comment: Would you please clarify: "My trouble is that I cannot find the poles and the residues." Does that mean you are not allowed to or that you don't know how to?

Comment: @did ok now i have this "exponetials" form , ho do i proceed ?

Comment: @Ennar i don't know i can procede , i can finde that z=0 is a pole of order 2 but calculating the residuoes is difficolut beacuse i use the formula with the derivate but the limit is pretty hard

Comment: "ho(w) do i proceed ?" It seems I already told you how, probably twice. Did you write down the $t$-integral? Why not?

Comment: @Did ahh ok maybe i understand , because the integral is on the unit circle i can calculate the integral between 0 and 2pi. i use z= $e^{it}$ and  so it cames   $\frac{e^{it}}{\sin^{3}(e^{it}/2)} * ie^{it}$ , the funcition is even ( but it's even or odd) ? so the integral is 0 ?

Comment: ps @Did sorry for my bad english , i'm italian.

Comment: Sooo... the integral is $$\int_0^{2\pi}f(t)ie^{it}dt=\int_0^\pi f(t)ie^{it}dt+\int_\pi^{2\pi}f(t)ie^{it}dt$$ and $$\int_\pi^{2\pi}f(t)ie^{it}dt=\int_0^\pi\cdots$$ (See how insisting of writing down $f(t)$ explicitely is only **preventing** you to go further...)

Comment: @Did so i can write it as 2 $\int_{}(f(t)...)$ ?

Comment: What? Did you write down the integral from $\pi$ to $2\pi$ as an integral from $0$ to $\pi$? If not, why?

Comment: @did yes i can write as 2 *(integral from $0$ to $\pi$) right ? ps thk for your help

Comment: ?? No, the integral on $(\pi,2\pi)$ is not twice an integral on $(0,\pi)$. Just write down the details for real and you will see...

Comment: @Did i'm so sorry but i really can't understand. :(

Comment: Just a curiosity: do you have a pencil in your hand and a piece of paper in front of you?

Comment: yes ,of course i have

Comment: maybe the integral from 0 to 2$\pi$ i can write as 2(integral from 0 to $\pi$)

Comment: "maybe the integral from 0 to 2π..." Again? You are supposed to look at the integral **from 0 to π** in my comment from 2 hours ago. If you don't, we cannot make progress.

Comment: @Did as integral from 0 to pi of f(t)+f(t+pi) ?